# Thread Error while accessing jtable row in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am getting console Error - and unable to access the row value

> MDIWindow.frames.VolumeCharting_Calc$Save.updateRow(VolumeCharting_Calc.java:497)
>   MDIWindow.frames.VolumeCharting_Calc$Save.run(VolumeCharting_Calc.java:363)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My Code

```
sumTotal += resp.getVolume();
long numb = Long.parseLong((String) jTable2.getValueAt(rowToUpdate, 6)); // ERROR LINE
double totalPerc = ((double) numb / sumTotal) * 100;
```

Why am I getting an error here - where else I have similar code to get value ... Before this code as well.

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: U are not providing enough information here. But please keep in mind that Swing is NOT multithreaded. Meaning, altough it will work a lot of the time, you should dispatch all accesses to swing classes to the wing worker (with SwingUtilities.invoke)

Comment: Swing is not thread safe and you should notify it's state from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I am able to read and write the jtable values in the thread else where because I have used `ExecutorService que = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` ... but only here I am getting this Error ....  @F. Lumnitz - I have already given the Full stracktrace.. This Error lines above shown are repetitive...<br> Can any1 please help

Comment: Make sure you're only making changes to the UI on the UI thread. Either via a specified delegate method, or via a publicly exposed method that allows your worker class to post a message back to the UI, for the UI to then process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your suspected code in UI thread and see what happens,

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {                  
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             sumTotal += resp.getVolume();
                             long numb = Long.parseLong((String)  jTable2.getValueAt(rowToUpdate, 6)); // ERROR LINE
                             double totalPerc = ((double) numb / sumTotal) * 100;
                        }
 });
```